# readfile downloads corrupt files

Tags: php, download, readfile

I am facing a problem when i am trying to download a certain file from my localhost. Everytime i download a file, either a .docx, a .pdf or a .png it is always corrupt. I have spend multiple hours on finding a solution but nothing seems to work.

This is the script im running :

```
$file_download="loonadministratie/{$loon_id}/{$file}";
        if (file_exists($file_download)) {
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream/loonadministratie/{$loon_id}/");
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file_download));
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_download));
                readfile($file_download);
                exit;
            }
```

Thanks in forehand

Comment: what do you mean by "corrupt"?

Comment: Try adding: `header('Content-transfer-encoding: binary');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
if (ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();
?>
```

It may be the issue